# wordpress archives appear in google search

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress site and my archives pages are showing in google search.

For instance, see the 2nd listing in this search:

How can I prevent this from happening?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should check your SEO plugin settings and also you can search more about robot.txt for seo crawling

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove it first from Google index (using search console) then disallow search engine access using a common plugin named SEO Toast.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "Yoast Seo" plugin then you can set noindex from plugins settings. Also you can remove it from Google Webmaster Tool's search console.